# How to dynamically load localization resource data without rebilding the application?

Tags: dynamic, localization, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm using localization in my `Blazor Server` app. I need to add key, value pairs to localization resource file programmatically. I have inputs in my UI. User will able to add key, value pairs through the application UI. But after that I need that inserted data to be available with localization(After refreshing the browser) without re-building the application. Is there a way to dynamically load `.resx` resource file data without rebuilding the application in `Blazor Server` app after it get changed while running?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your request:

You can store the resource strings to database and create a Cache to store the last updated data of resources.

It's work fine if your resource less than 4MB.